# How should I resign from new job after one shift?

Tags: resignation, part-time, retail

I have only had one shift (induction) at my new job but i really didn't enjoy it. It's only a part time sunday shift at a retail store but I didn't like the people and the tasks involved. I know many people will say give it time, everyone hates their first shift but I still have my old job as I decided not to resign unless i enjoyed it. I didn't know how to go about resigning as i have only had one shift, wasn't sure if i should call the store or hand in a letter on my next shift which will be in 3 days.

Thankyou x

Comment: Call your "new" boss and tell him the job isn't a good fit.  He will value knowing sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 8):

**Let your boss know as soon as possible.**  Waiting until your next shift will cause more inconvenience for your boss, as they will be scrambling to cover the shift.  And there's no benefit for you in waiting, anyway.

**In person or on the phone is preferable** for an important communication such as a resignation.  You should do it this way if possible.  It's less pleasant for you, but learning to be able to do this is a good skill.

Also, I think it's worth mentioning that **you acted unprofessionally in officially accepting a job but not really being fully committed to take it.**  The expectation of employers would be that accepting a position means you actually plan to do it, and have freed yourself from any conflicting obigations--not that you will start working and only then make up your mind. Yeah, I know it's a low-level service job, the employer's commitment to you is minimal, and there is turnover all the time, but still, I don't think this is an acceptable course of action.  It's going make a bad impression on the people involved.  That may not cost you now at this level, but doing this with a higher level position could be quite detrimental to your career.

Comment: It's not unprofessional at all.

Comment: @Strawberry, it is exceedingly unprofessional.